# Web.config reuse the same section or field

Tags: .net, configuration, web-config

In my web.config I have many redundant values, for example the connection string.

```
<nhibernate><connectionString>....</connectionString></nhibernate>
<log4net><connectionString>....</connectionString></log4net>
```

is there a way to declare the value and reuse it in different section,In this way refactoring would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? I don't see anything redundant here. The first ConnectionString is for nhibernate and the second one for log4net.

Comment: assume that I want to use the same connection string in both sections.<x>myconnectionstring</x> and then <nhib>x</nib> and <log>x</log> for example

Comment: Maybe you can refactor like this:
<connectionStrings>
    <default>...</default>
    <nhibernate>...</nhibernate>
    <log4net>...</log4net>
</connectionStrings>

Then you can see if there is a value for what you want, and if you don't find it, you use the default.